# WinBUGS truncated normal distribution

Tags: mixed-model, normal-distribution, bugs, truncation

I am estimating a stochastic frontier with a mixed model.
So far the half normal distribution worked good but I need a truncated normal distribution. It does not work, and I receive the error „Expected collection operator c“. I am using R2WinBUGS and as you can see in the model I have tried OpenBUGS and WinBUGS. Any suggestion?
My model looks like:

```
for (i in 1:N)
 {

    mu[i] <- alpha + x[i,1]*beta[1] + x[i,2]*beta[2] + x[i,3]*beta[3] + 
         x[i,4]*beta[4] + x[i,5]*beta[5] + u0[county[i]] + u1[county[i]]*x[i,1] + 
         u2[county[i]]*x[i,2] + u3[county[i]]*x[i,3] + u4[county[i]]*x[i,4] + 
         u5[county[i]]*x[i,5] - z[ID[i]]

    y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)

}


for (i in 1:220) {
    z[i] ~ djl.dnorm.trunc(rho,lambda,0,1000)

    z[i] ~ dnorm(rho,lambda)T(0,100)  #For openbugs

    eff[i] <- exp(-z[i])
}
```

prior for `rho~dnorm(0,0.027)`

I would appreciate your help!
Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Is this question *only* about how to get something done in R / WinBUGS? If so, it would be off-topic for CV (see our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)), but on topic for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If you have a substantive statistical question, please edit to clarify it, if not, you can flag your Q for migration (*please don't cross-post, though*).

Comment: The function `djl.dnorm.trunc` looks suspicious to me. Why don't you use the `dnorm(..)I(..)` here also?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I tried that one too and it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

For truncating, I use the operator `I` i.e.:

```
x ~ dnorm(mean, tau)I(low, high)
```

Comment: @DanielC Your error will be probably caused by different line of code than this one...